# What plane is Area in, in this equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I have the equation $$F = (NI)^2\mu_0\frac{\text{Area}}{2g^2}$$
Which calculates the force of an electromagnet. I was wondering if anyone knew what plane Area is taken from? I have heard it is the cross sectional area of electromagnet(which doesn't make sense to me because it already uses the number of turns, N and the current, I), I have heard is is the cross-sectional area of plane **b**, and I have heard it as the cross sectional area of plane **a**. I have also heard it as plain "Area".

A ferromagnetic cylinder being acted on by an electromagnet.(Assume this cylinder is being drawn into a solenoid circle-side first)

[image]

Personally, I think it uses the cross sectional area of plane **b**.

Being a physics problem, can anyone confirm whether or not I should be using the area from plane **b**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is the cross sectional area of the core, plane b in your drawing.

See http://info.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Workshop/advice/coils/force.html#nfringe for more information.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I thought I was using the right one, but I was not certain. (Non of my sources said anything besides A = Area)